# How can I check if a database table exists or not with Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like to check if a database table exists or not, but I don't know how to do.

I wrote (for example with SQLite, although I use MySQL mainly),

```
import sqlite3
table_name = "some_table"
connection = sqlite3.connect(db)
cursor = connection.cursor()
table_check = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name={};".format(table_name)
if not cursor.execute(table_check).fetchone():  # if the table doesn't exist
# OR if cursor.execute(table_check).fetchone() == "":
    create_table()
else:
    update_table()
```

But, an Error occured and I cannot proceed.

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: some_table

I read several Q&A here, but I couldn't get those.
Any advice can help me.
Thank you.

Python 3.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is depending on what rdbms product (mysql, sqlite, ms sql, etc.) you use.

You are getting this particular error in your above query because you do not enclose the value of table_name variable in single quotes.

In mysql you can use [information_schema.tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html) table to query if a table exists.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Shadow. Ah, sorry, table_name in format() is variable. Sorry, I might make you confused. I changed. I am using SQLite as a test because it's easy to use. And thank you for the link.

Comment: Still, you need to enclose the table_name by single quotes. Your sql in the current format will be: `...WHERE type='table' AND name=mytable;`, but you need `...WHERE type='table' AND name='mytable';`

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood what you wrote. My English is poor! Yes, you are right, I had to write name='{}'. Thank you for your advice.